# How to use GAS classes in different files, independent of file load order?

Tags: google-apps-script, global-variables

Consider a following simple example, file **country.gs**

```
class Country { }
```

and file file **subcountry.gs**

```
class SubCountry extends Country{ }

function test(){}
```

Trying to run test() I get

```
ReferenceError: Country is not defined
```

If I join files or change loading order, it works fine.

Apparently, I don't want to be dependent on file load order, also clasp changes on push(sorting alphabetically), so it's definitely not a good way to rename files in order they should be compiled.

Is there an appropriate solution for this?

Example:

https://script.google.com/d/1Pipt3YN1FBGkbRRT2PyCHhugd-Xrv3zctIWYwX-cGnAjXfDckwOk7bJh/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The following link may help: [https://ramblings.mcpher.com/apps-script/apps-script-v8/multiple-script-files/](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/apps-script/apps-script-v8/multiple-script-files/)

Comment: Is that a global?

Comment: @TheMaster - yes, it's as easy as it is in example, I've added a link to "working" example

Comment: @Alan Wells - that's a good article, but it doesn't answer my question, as that guy doesn't use class inheritance based on "extends" keyword, and you cannot closure that declaration

Comment: Solution is to avoid using global variables.

Comment: Is class declaration considered a global variable?

Comment: Anything declared in global scope is a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65648174/1329498) posted by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) and the Bruce Mcpherson [article](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/apps-script/apps-script-v8/multiple-script-files/) shared by [Alan Wells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946873/alan-wells), you could try implementing your own [`require()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9901097/1329498) function.

```
/* Code.gs */
function test() {
  const SubCountry = require("SubCountry");
  const x = new SubCountry();
}
```

```
/* SubCountry.gs */
function SubCountry() {
  const Country = require("Country");
  return class SubCountry extends Country {};
}
```

```
/* Country.gs */
function Country() {
  return class Country {};
}
```

```
/* Require.gs */
function require(moduleName) {
  const modules = {
    Country: Country,
    SubCountry: SubCountry,
  };
  
  return modules[moduleName]();
}
```

Alternatively, you could apply a more direct approach without the use of `require()`, but I find this to be slightly less intuitive.

```
/* Code.gs */
function test() {
  const x = new (SubCountryClass())();
}
```

```
/* SubCountry.gs */
function SubCountryClass() {
  return class SubCountry extends CountryClass() {};
}
```

```
/* Country.gs */
function CountryClass() {
  return class Country {};
}
```

All files above, for both approaches, are intentionally presented and loaded in an order that would cause a ReferenceError if declaring the classes globally. So this should be fully independent of load order.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting wrap of Masters example. Might require some refactoring from me, but really explicit, so I might try it. Besides anyway I have to maintain full module list for exporting in other projects

Answer (score 5):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_calling_functions_before_they_are_parsed),

> This arrangement is identical to how browsers handle multiple  tags in one HTML file.

Each file is like a new `<script>file content </script>` tag and they're added in the order they appear in Apps script editor. This is a problem only when you're using global variables. It's explicitly discouraged to use global variables.

> Caution: It's not best practice to rely on a specific file parse order to avoid this issue. The sequence of script file parsing can change if script files are copied, removed, renamed, or otherwise rearranged. It's better to remove any global variable dependency on function calls if possible.

[Classes are infact "special functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). You can always enclose the `Class` in a local scope and call, when needed as recommended in the documentation.

#### Snippet:

Just moving the calling function to local scope should work

```
/*subcountry.gs*/

function test(){
  /*local scope*/class SubCountry extends Country{ }
}
```

To avoid  declaring class in global scope as well:

```
/*country.gs*/
var Country;

function main(){
  if (Country == undefined) Country = class Country { }
  return Country;
}
```

```
/*subcountry.gs*/

function test(){
  /*initialize class Country*/main()
  /*local scope*/class SubCountry extends Country{ }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to expand your answer to include how the OP's code could be written to follow your recommendation of avoiding global scope declarations?

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably go with one of solutions described here

[TypeScript classes order in Google AppScript Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802430/typescript-classes-order-in-google-appscript-project)

using **clasp** and it's **filePushOrder** option

```
{
  "scriptId":"1Pipt3YN1FBGkbRRT2PyCHhugd-Xrv3zctIWYwX-cGnAjXfDckwOk7bJh",
  "filePushOrder": [
    "country.gs",
    "subcountry.gs"
  ]
}
```

Author example
https://github.com/PopGoesTheWza/clasp-filePushOrder

I enforces me to use clasp, but at least it's easy to maintain.